# Include javascript from vendor/assets/javascripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, include, include-path

How do you include a javascript file located in vendor/assets/javascripts in a single view file (NOT in application.js) ?

Some kind of `javascript_include_tag` ? Please help me with syntax

I have tried the following and it doesn't work:

- javascript_include_tag 'respond'
- javascript_include_tag 'respond.js'
- javascript_include_tag 'vendor/assets/javascripts/respond'
- javascript_include_tag 'vendor/assets/javascripts/respond.js'

Thank you

Comment: answered yourself? ;)

Comment: Haha, kind of but i don't know exactly what to put in the parameter? The file is respond.js.. I have tried 'respond.js', 'respond' and 'vendor/assets/javascripts/respond.js', none of which work

Comment: 1.use browser console 2. `view page source` check if file is loaded

Comment: your first try should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "your_file" %>
```

If you're trying to include `respond.js`, you could check out the [respond_rails](https://github.com/gevans/respond-rails) gem, which will allow you to include this in your view:

```
<%= respond_include_tags %>
```

In your views of course

Answer (score 0):

This may be an old question but for others who are looking for an answer that works for any js file, eg: `vendor/assets/randomfolder/anotherfolder/custom.js`, then to include `custom.js` using `javascript_include_tag` inside an individual view file, you would need to add the following line of code into `assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( anotherfolder/custom.js )
```

The path here is `anotherfolder/custom.js` instead of `randomfolder/anotherfolder/custom.js` is because any folder/file inside `vendor/assets/` is automatically added to rails assets pipeline path / sprokets search path. Note that deep folders are not added, thus the `anotherfolder/custom.js` path.

After adding that line to `assets.rb`, you can now use `javascript_include_tag anotherfolder/custom.js` inside any view file without issues.

---

ADDITIONALLY, if you do not want to keep typing out the subdirectory `anotherfolder`, then you can go to `application.rb` and add it into the assets pipeline/sprokets path with the following code:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "randomfolder", "anotherfolder")
```

After doing so, you can now use `javascript_include_tag custom.js`. Using this method for limited case is ok, but to include all subdirectories (including deeper ones) is not recommended.

NOTE: Please remember to restart the server so that load paths can be updated